# ASP.NET MVC 4 - How do I access the http://localhost/reports page from within the application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

I have developed an application that shows a specific report from the report server using MVC 4. What I want is to actually show the http://localhost/reports interface without the need to log in (accessed via the server) and with the possibility of passing credentials with it (domain, username and password). How do I achieve that?

[image: Interface]
This is the interface I want to show.

It does not matter for me if it is in an `iframe` or inside the `.aspx` view.

Comment: The only viable way to do this is to frame the report website. However, if you do that, it will only work if the client of this site is on the same network as the report server. In other words, you can't have the report server be only available via your internal network and expose this site that frames it to the external network.

Comment: You could encrypt the credentials and pass them in the url for the iFrame.

Comment: @KevinRaffay yes, but you can't do that with Internet explorer and I need to be able to use that.

Comment: I am going to create an interface in my web application that views, deletes and edits security settings of the reports